# Does a PHP page get interrupted when multiple users request it at the same time?

Tags: php, wamp

For example if we have a certain php file on server `getProducts.php`. Does it get interrupted when multiple users request it at the same time?
for example if a user asks for details about product A, and another user about product B, and another user about a product C, etc...will php be interrupted? or it's a self generated threading system that works and respond upon and to each request?

Thank you!

Comment: No, you can only have one visitor on your site at any given time.

Comment: Also removed the java and android tags, as the question has nothing to do with java or android.

Comment: What webserver are you using to server your php code?

Comment: For the record, PHP is single threaded.  If you want to handle multiple simultaneous requests then you need to use a web server in front of PHP that either forks or uses threads.

Comment: @sberry wamp server. ok then what should I do to solve my problem?? :S

Comment: @AlanDeep You haven't stated what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you sberry i just noticed your second answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using apache, it's a concurrent system. That means each request will be handled in parallel so your php script will not be interrupted.

Answer (score 8):

This has, unexpectedly, little or nothing to do with PHP. It's not PHP that answers the user's request but the *web server*. For example Apache, NginX, IIS, and so on.

The web server then routes the call to a PHP instance that is usually independent of any other request being satisfied in that exact moment. The number of concurrent requests depends on the server configuration, architecture, and platform capabilities. So-called "C10K" servers are designed to front up to ten thousand connections simultaneously.

But PHP is not the only factor in the process that goes from "GET /index.php" to a bunch of HTML; any active page (PHP or ASP or Python etc.) may request further resources from, say, a database. In that case a concurrency problem arises, and whenever two users need to acquire the same resource (a row in a data table, the whole table, a log file...), some sort of  *semaphore system* makes it so that only one of them at a time can acquire a "lock" on that specific resource, and all others must wait for their turn, even if the overlying web server is capable of handling hundreds or thousands of concurrent connections.

**Update on performance issues**: the same happens *within* PHP for things such as **sessions**. Imagine you have a single user requesting a single page and that page has code to generate ten more calls (to images, pop-ups, ads, AJAX...). The first request opens a *session*, which is a bunch of data that must remain coherent. So when the other ten calls come by, all bound to the same session, and PHP has no way of knowing whether any one of these calls wants to *modify* session data -- it has no recourse but to [prevent the second call from proceeding](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/) until the first call has released the session lock, and once it does, the second call will block the third, and so on. Take-away point: avoiding `session_start()` if it is not needed (e.g. replacing it with cryptographically strong GET tokens or doing without altogether), or calling `session_commit()` as soon as you are finished modifying `_SESSION`'s values, **will greatly improve performances**. (So will using a faster session manager, or one that doesn't do coarse lock: e.g. `redis`).

For example in image generation:

```
session_start();
// This does the magic.
session_commit();
// We can still read session. We just can't write it anymore.

// That's why we needed a session.
if (!isset($_SESSION['authorized'])) {
    Header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    die();
}
// Here the code that generates an image *and sends* it. The session
// lock, if we hadn't committed, will *not* expire until the request
// has been processed by the *client* with network slowness. (Things
// go much better if you use the CGI interface instead of module).
```

In your example and seeing the "WAMP" tags, you have a Windows Apache serving data retrieved from MySQL by PHP, and serving requests on products.

The Apache server will receive hundreds of connections, activate hundreds of instances of PHP module (they'll share most of their code, so memory occupation doesn't go up disastrously fast), and then all these instances will ask to MySQL, "What about product XYZ?". In MySQL parlance they will try to obtain a `READ LOCK`. Read lock means something like, "I'm reading this thing, so please none of you dare *write* on it until I'm finished". But all of them are just reading, so they will all succeed - concurrently.

So no, there will be no stops -- just then.

But suppose you also want to update a counter of product views. Then every PHP instance also needs a `WRITE LOCK`, which means, "I want to write on this thing, so none of you read until I'm finished or you'll risk reading half-baked data, and of course none of you *write* here while I'm going at it".

At this point, the table type counts. MyISAM tables have [table locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html): if the instance updating product A's statistics is writing on `product_views`, no other instance will be able to do anything *with that whole table*. They will all queue and wait. If the table is `InnoDB`, the lock is at *row* level - all instances updating product A will queue one after the other, parallel to those updating product B, C, D and so on. So if all instances are writing to different records, they'll run in parallel.

That's why you really want to use InnoDB tables in these cases.

Of course, if you have a record such as "page visits", and they are all updating the row for "product-page.php", you have a bottleneck right there, and in case of a high traffic site, you'd do well if you designed some other way of writing that information (one of many workarounds is to store it in a shared memory location; every now and then *one* of the many instances accessing it receives the task of saving the information to the database. The instances still compete for locking on the memory, but that's orders of magnitude faster than competing for a database transaction).

Comment: I do not know exactly how to frame the answer, I tried the "not too technical" approach. Feel free to correct me if I guessed wrong or need clarification/further information.